# SugarCRM: Coding a Custom Middle Name field

Tags: field, sugarcrm

I'm trying to create a Custom Field in SugarOS 6 to store Middle Names. Designing and implementing the field in **EditView** was easy enough with the Studio. But I'm stuck when it comes to displaying the concatenated name parts in **DetailView** (i.e. **Salutation + First Name + Middle Name + Last Name**).

Foraging through the Sugar Forums [**got me to this thread**](http://www.sugarcrm.com/forums/showthread.php?p=233680#post233680) which describes a way it can be done. I've implemented the code given there in the form of a Sugar logic hook that utilizes the **after_retrieve** hook that is called upon the loading of a record.

Here's my hook code:

```
$hook_array['after_retrieve'] = Array(); 
$hook_array['after_retrieve'][] = array(
        100, 
        'set_full_name', 
        'custom/modules/Leads/leads_custom_logic.php', 
        'LeadsCustomLogic', 
        'setFullName'
);
```

And here's the function that is being called:

```
function setFullName( &$focus, $event, $arguments ) {
    $name = $focus->salutation . ' ' . 
            $focus->first_name . ' ' .
            ( $focus->middle_name_c ? ( $focus->middle_name_c . ' ' ) : '' ) . 
            $focus->last_name;
    $focus->name = $name;
    $focus->full_name = $name;
    // echo $focus->full_name;
}
```

The hook and the called code seems to work fine and if I uncomment the last line (echo) the full name is dumped all over the screen (wherever this function is called). However, **it's not displaying where it's actually supposed to**, i.e. the row in the DetailView screen where the full name appears.

Any ideas?

Thanks,
m^e

Answer (score 1):

maybe just change **detailview.php** and add the following to your full name field defs

```
'customCode' => '{$fields.salutation.value} {$fields.first_name.value} {$fields.midle_name_c.value} {$fields.last_name.value}'
```

as a new `key => value` in array and the custom code will be displayed instead of full_name value.

Comment: That's a cool quick fix. Thanks :) But I'm looking for a way through which the $bean->full_name (for Leads) is going to produce a concatenated result of all 3 fields. I traced back the routine that does this to the routine named _create_proper_name_field() in the Person class in include/SugarObjects. Am trying to figure out a way to safely override this routine as doing so will reflect the change in all possible views in Sugar.